# Constructing a model inside another model

Tags: set-theory

Suppose a model $M$ that satisfies $ZF$ and take a model $N$ in the universe $M$. Let
$$|N'| = \{a \in |M|; M \models a \,\epsilon\, |N|\},$$
where $|A|$ is the underlying set/collection of the model $A$ and <$a \,\epsilon\, |N|$> is the formula for <$a \in |N|$>.

Now $$a \in_M |N'| \Leftrightarrow (a \in M) \land (M \models a \,\epsilon\, |N|) \Leftrightarrow (a \in M) \land (Val(a \,\epsilon\, |N|, M) = 1) \\\Leftrightarrow (a \in M) \land (\{(x, a), (y, |N|)\} \in Val(x \,\epsilon\,y, M)) \Leftrightarrow (a \in M) \land (a \in_M |N|) \Leftrightarrow a \in_M |N|$$
So shouldn't the sets $|N'|$ and $|N|$ be equal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement $$a \in_M |N'| \Leftrightarrow (a \in M) \land (M \models a \,\epsilon\, |N|)$$ is incorrect.  The set $|N'|$ is probably not even an element of $M$, so it is meaningless to write $a \in_M |N'|$.  Rather, what is true is $$a \in |N'| \Leftrightarrow (a \in M) \land (M \models a \,\epsilon\, |N|).$$  So $|N'|$ is the set whose *actual* elements are the $M$-elements of $|N|$ (that is, the elements of $|N|$ according to the element relation of the structure $(M,\epsilon)$).

Comment: So $N'$ is a model in $\mathscr U$ and $N$ is a model in $M$?

Comment: Right, $N'$ is what you get when you take the structure $N$ and turn it into a structure in the actual universe rather than inside $M$.

Comment: There is something to be said about transitive models here, though.

Comment: It is a crucial property of Godel's constructible class $ L$ that $L=L^L.$  That is if $\psi$ is the (rather long, but finite) formula in one free variable  where $x\in L$  means (literally) $\psi(x),$  then $\forall x\; (\psi (x)\iff \psi^L(x)\;).  $